# Mining multiple hashtags simultaneously in R

Tags: r, twitter, mining

I'm a bit new to R, so this question might seem very basic. I would like to produce lists based on more than one hashtags in R. I designed an application which mines the tweets for #AT&T when I put it in the search box or #Verizon when I put that in. Any suggestions how I can mine tweets that have both these hashtags in them (something like this tweet "xyxyxyxxyxyxy #AT&T xyxyxyx #Verizon xyxy").

Comment: What do you call application? A shiny application?

Comment: Yes, it's a shiny app

Comment: Just use the keyword `AND`. Please take a look to [twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets).